# Android textview adapter is not returning id of particular textview find with tag

Tags: java, android, textview, adapter, android-adapter

I am learning android development and working on a small game app. So here is my code which is working,

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View gridViewContent = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.game_grid_view_content, null);

    final TextView tv = (TextView) gridViewContent.findViewById(R.id.g_v_content);
    tv.setHeight((gridViewHeight/8)+5);
    tv.setTag(position + 501);
    tv.setId(position + 1001);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(
            ((TextView)gridViewContent.findViewWithTag(tv.getTag())).getId()
    ));
```

So this is working and setting text to all textviews like 1001, 1002, 1003 etc. But when I am trying to get ID of particular textview by changing

```
((TextView)gridViewContent.findViewWithTag(501)).getId();
```

which is my first `TextView`, so instead of setting text 1001 to all TV, app is crashed with `NullPointerException`. So can anyone tell me how can I target particular text view by id or tag or anything? I used 501 just for example, because I will use int variable to store previously clicked TV's id or tag. I tried to find view by id but it is also not working.

Thank you for your time. Remember, I am still new at android and learning and looking for help to find where I am wrong.

Here is my textview adapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View contextView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View gridViewContent = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.game_grid_view_content, null);

            final TextView tv = (TextView) gridViewContent.findViewById(R.id.g_v_content);
            tv.setHeight((gridViewHeight / 8) + 5);
            tv.setTag(position + 501);
            tv.setId(position + 1001);

        TextView textView = null;
        ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) parent.getParent();
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < row.getChildCount(); itemPos++) {
            View view = row.getChildAt(itemPos);
            if (view instanceof TextView) { //do a getTag here and get the textView you need
                textView = (TextView) view; //Found it!
                break;
            }
        }

        tv.setText(String.valueOf(
                textView.getId()
        ));
}
```

And here is my layout xml file code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    tools:context="io.github.viralj.matchfun.PlayGameActivity"
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/play_game_current_score"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/current_score"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/play_game_high_score"
        android:id="@+id/high_score"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/current_score"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/high_score"
        android:background="#bdc3c7"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/playGameGridTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1sp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="1sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        </GridView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are ... mistaking those two tags.

setTag() can attach ANY object to the view, while the XML tag is only a string - I believe the findViewByTag will try to match the tag passed thru XML, not one attached through code - as it could be any object.
**EDIT**

Get hold of the parent layout. Then get all children of that parent layout. Something line this:

```
 TextView textView = null; 
    ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
    for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < row.getChildCount(); itemPos++) {
        View view = row.getChildAt(itemPos);
 if (view instanceof TextView) { //do a getTag here and get the textView you need
             textView = (TextView) view; //Found it!
             break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay so I tried and used findViewById and passed id 1001 which didn't work either. So any suggestion, how to get data of particular textview?

Comment: The reason is that it is getting text view at 0, and before grid view I have two text views.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. In  ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();, v is your gridViewContent.

Comment: Ok. lets go step by step. Comment this chunk of code
 TextView textView = null;
        ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) parent.getParent();
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < row.getChildCount(); itemPos++) {
            View view = row.getChildAt(itemPos);
            if (view instanceof TextView) { //do a getTag here and get the textView you need
                textView = (TextView) view; //Found it!
                break;
            }
        }

Comment: Then replace  tv.setText(String.valueOf(
                textView.getId()
        )); with  tv.setText(String.valueOf(
                textView.getTag()
        ));

Comment: I am not able to understand your codes in comment. can you update your answer with new codes?

Comment: Comment the code that I posted earlier. and replace textView.getId() with textView.getTag()

Comment: Hey @Shishir, I found my solution. I had to hack into codes. All I needed to do is get it from parent view without any condition or anything. Thanx for helping me out. ;)